# Mockito - how to access .when argument in .thenReturn method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mocking, mockito

When the `.get()` method on my `getter` object is called, it usually sends a request to an API. For the mock version of the Getter object, I want `.getFile()` to return the result of calling `reader.readLocalFile()` with the same argument (to avoid making a real HTTP request).

My current code is in the form:

```
Mockito.when(mockGetter.get(file1)).thenReturn(reader.readLocalFile(file1));
Mockito.when(mockGetter.get(file2)).thenReturn(reader.readLocalFile(file2));
Mockito.when(mockGetter.get(file3)).thenReturn(reader.readLocalFile(file3));
(etc.)
```

where `file1`, `file2` and `file3` are string literals.

Would it be possible to make it look more like the following?

```
Mockito.when(mockGetter.get(someString)).thenReturn(reader.readLocalFile(thatSameString));
```

Answer (score 1):

Mockito answers can be used to access the arguments of a mock, something along these lines:

```java
Answer<String> answer = inv -> reader.readLocalFile(inv.getArgument(0));
doAnswer(answer).when(mockGetter).get(anyString());
```

Comment: [Heres the documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Java_8_Custom_Answers). There's [another version `thenAnswer()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs) but it's not as clean.